# Prevent TextFormField from losing focus when enter key is pressed in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a `TextFormField` in a Flutter app and I don't want it to lose focus when the user presses enter, which is the default behavior. I've tried a couple of things involving giving the field a `FocusNode`:

##### 1) `FocusNode` and `onKeyEvent` (does not work)

In this approach, the conditional was never true.

In `initState`:

```dart
_focusNode = FocusNode(onKeyEvent: (node, event) {
  if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.enter) {
    return KeyEventResult.handled;
  }
  return KeyEventResult.ignore;
});
```

##### 2) `FocusNode` and `requestFocus` (works)

This approach works but feels hacky. I'm wondering if there is a simpler or more straightforward way.

In `initState`:

```dart
_focusNode = FocusNode();
```

In `build`:

```dart
TextFormField(
  focusNode: _focusNode,
  onFieldSubmitted: (_) => _focusNode.requestFocus(),
);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the `textInputAction` parameter,

```
TextField(
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.none,
  ...
)
```

Comment: It looks like they're wanting to use `TextFormField` and not `TextField` but the constructor for `TextFormField` also has that parameter... might want to edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution to this problem is to add `keyboardType` parameter and pass `TextInputType.multiline`.

```
TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  ...
)
```